# How to check for a breakpoint before deploying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am using pry to have breakpoints in a Rails app, but as the code gets messier I sometimes forget to remove the binding.pry from code I just debugged for a hot fix.

As I see it I have three choices to handle this:

1. Have tests and deploy only if tests pass
2. Before deploy check for binding.pry in all `.rb` files and if any found to have a warning and don't deploy
3. Have a helper to wrap `binding.pry` and if it's production environment to have noop

Obviously the first option is the best. How would I create the second option? Using Rake or Shell or Capistrano?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Git for your source control, you should write a pre-commit hook.
You can use whatever language you like, as long as it is executable.

Here's one I use. I don't remember exactly where I found it. (Edit: looks like it may have come from [here](https://github.com/twe4ked/git-pre-commit/blob/master/pre-commit))

It is named `<your project>/.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
hits = []

checks = {
            #'_spec\.rb$' => ['focus:[:space:]*true'],
            '\.rb$' => ['binding\.pry', 'debugger'],
            '\.coffee' => ['console\.log'],
            '\.js' => ['console\.log']
         }

# Find the names of all the filenames that have been (A)dded (C)opied or (M)odified
filenames = `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM`.split("\n")

filenames.each do |filename|
  # Perform special checks for _spec filenames (rspec tests)
  checks.each do |filename_pattern, patterns|
    if filename.match filename_pattern
      patterns.each do |contents_pattern|
        results = `git diff --cached  #{filename} | grep "^\+[^+]" | grep "#{contents_pattern}"`.split("\n").map { |r| r.sub(/^\+[\s\t]*/, '') }
        if $? == 0
          # Add the relevant change with line number to the hits array
          results.each{ |r|
            hits.push "#{filename}:" + `grep -n '#{r}' #{filename}`.sub(/:\s+/, ' ').chomp
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

if hits.any?
  puts "\e[33m>>> Please remove the following problems from these files before committing\e[0m"
  puts hits.join("\n")
end

exit 1 if hits.any?
```

Comment: also for anyone that using this as a new file, don't forget to chmod u+x so it will be executable, unless you are editing the sample file

Comment: Had to comeback and say thanks again, really helpful!